# Storing multiple arrays within multiple arrays within an array Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I have a text file with 93 columns and 1699 rows that I have imported into Python. The first three columns do not contain data that is necessary for what I'm currently trying to do. Within each column, I need to divide each element (aka row) in the column by all of the other elements (rows) in that same column. The result I want is an array of 90 elements where each of 1699 elements has 1699 elements.

A more detailed description of what I'm attempting: I begin with Column3. At Column3, Row1 is to be divided by all the other rows (including the value in Row1) within Column3. That will give Row1 1699 calculations. Then the same process is done for Row2 and so on until Row1699. This gives Column3 1699x1699 calculations. When the calculations of all of the rows in Column 3 have completed, then the program moves on to do the same thing in Column 4 for all of the rows. This is done for all 90 columns which means that for the end result, I should have 90x1699x1699 calculations.

My code as it currently is is:

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

fnames = glob("NIR_data.txt")
arrays = np.array([np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=1) for f in fnames])
NIR_values = np.concatenate(arrays)
NIR_band = NIR_values.T

C_values = []

for i in range(3,len(NIR_band)):
    for j in range(0,len(NIR_band[3])):
        loop_list = NIR_band[i][j]/NIR_band[i,:]
        C_values.append(loop_list)
```

What it produces is an array of 1699x1699 dimension. Each individual array is the results from the Row calculations. Another complaint is that the code takes ages to run. So, I have two questions, is it possible to create the type of array I'd like to work with? And, is there a faster way of coding this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing each of the numbers in a given column by each of the other values in the same column can be accomplished in one operation as follows.

```
result = a[:, numpy.newaxis, :] / a[numpy.newaxis, :, :]
```

Because looping over the elements happens in the optimized binary depths of numpy, this is as fast as Python is ever going to get for this operation.

If `a.shape` was `[1699,90]` to begin with, then the result will have shape `[1699,1699,90]`.  Assuming `dtype=float64`, that means you will need nearly 2 GB of memory available to store the result.

Comment: First off, Cheers for replying!!

It looks like numpy.newaxis is really close to what I need. The shape I'm looking for is actually [90,1699,1699]. I've just tried a few combinations of numpy.newaxis, but wasn't able to make it work. Is it possible?

Comment: You could start with `a = a.T` which means `a.shape` will be `[90,1699]` to start.  Then it's `a[:, np.newaxis, :] * a[ :, :, np.newaxis ]`.  Alternatively, you could also simply take my first solution and say `result = result.transpose([2,0,1])` at the end: this creates a new "view" of the numpy array with different dimension order and strides, but without needing to duplicate or move 2GB worth of content.

Comment: Oops: should have been `/`, not `*` in previous comment.   Note also: it's not really `numpy.newaxis` that's doing the magic for you.  You can also use `numpy.expand_dims`, or say something like `b = a.view(); c = a.view(); b.shape = [1699, 90, 1]; c.shape = [1699, 1, 90]; result = b/c`  The important thing is simply to get the dimensions aligned right before letting numpy do the hard work: the magic is then done by the "broadcasting" nature of the `/` operator when applied to numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First let's focus on the load:

```
arrays = np.array([np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=1) for f in fnames])
NIR_values = np.concatenate(arrays)
```

Your text talks about loading a file, and manipulating it.  But this clip loads multple files and joins them.

My first change is to collect the arrays in a list, not another array

```
alist = [np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=1) for f in fnames]
```

If you want to skip some columns, look at using the `usecols` parameter.  That may save you work later.

The elements of `alist` will now be 2d arrays (of floats).  If they are matching sizes `(N,M)`, they can be joined in various ways.  If there are `n` files, then

```
arrays = np.array(alist)  # (n,N,M) array
arrays = np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)   # (n*N, M) array
# similarly for axis=1
```

Your code does the same, but potentially confuses steps:

```
In [566]: arrays = np.array([np.ones((3,4)) for i in range(5)])
In [567]: arrays.shape
Out[567]: (5, 3, 4)     # (n,N,M) array
In [568]: NIR_values = np.concatenate(arrays)
In [569]: NIR_values.shape
Out[569]: (15, 4)       # (n*N, M) array
```

`NIR_band` is now `(4,15)`, and it's `len()` is the .shape[0]`, the size of the 1st dimension.`len(NIR_band[3])`is`shape[1]`, the size of the 2nd dimension.

You could skip the columns of `NIR_values` with `NIR_values[:,3:]`.

I get lost in the rest of text description.

The `NIR_band[i][j]/NIR_band[i,:]`, I would rewrite as `NIR_band[i,j]/NIR_band[i,:]`. What's the purpose of that?

As for you subject line, `Storing multiple arrays within multiple arrays within an array` - that sounds like making a 3 or 4d array.  `arrays` is 3d, `NIR_valus` is 2d.

Creating a (90,1699,1699) from a (93,1699) will probably involve (without iteration) a calculation analogous to:

```
In [574]: X = np.arange(13*4).reshape(13,4)
In [575]: X.shape
Out[575]: (13, 4)
In [576]: (X[3:,:,None]+X[3:,None,:]).shape
Out[576]: (10, 4, 4)
```

The last dimension is expanded with `None` (np.newaxis), and 2 versions broadcasted against each other.  `np.outer` does the multiplication of this calculation.